# Outlook 2010 - Windows Security Popup

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2010

Recently this started popping up when I have a email open & it is active. 
[image]

I did some googling & some sources pointed to a virus, but the scan returned nothing.

Any ideas???

Comment: Are we talking on your Personal or Company PC?

Comment: This is a normal window when Outlook needs to authenticate to the server and it needs to verify your credentials. Is the connection to `a1893.g.akamai.net` correct?

Comment: Ramhound - Company....

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a Windows 7 workstation.  Try clear the generic credentials in the Credential manager (found in control panel).